# Pass token from FirebaseAuth to Google Cast Custom Receiver in Android

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cast

I'm using Firebase and FirebaseUI for Android.

I want to pass the login state from my Android application to Google Cast Custom Receiver. Google Cast Custom Receiver will be written in HTML and JavaScript and deployed to Firebase Hosting.

How can I do that using the Firebase SDK?

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

The way to communicate with a Cast receiver is either through a custom message (using a custom namespace) or piggy-backing on media control commands that can take additional custom data. The first approach is the preferred one if you want bi-directional communication at will but the second one can do the job if your timing for sending a message can match with when you send a control command.